# Network Protocol implementation

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols

As part of a project work i am supposed to "implement" any network protocol of my choice. I googled for it but didnt find anything that would help a beginner like me to start off. Could anyone please give some ideas on where to begin? 
Thanks in advance!

PS: am not sure of the tags either.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols

Comment: If you are lazy, then implement the daytime protocol of RFC 867, it is only five lines of node.js :-) More seriously, is it really *any* protocol? There are many network protocols, of highly different complexities.

Answer (score 2):

You can try DHCP.  It is relatively simple and common.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol

To start you can cover the same subnet/vlan case. (Server client same subnet.)
Next do the different subnet/vlan case if you have time.

Comment: The Wikipedia article is OK but it would be better to warn the OP that, to *implement* a network protocol, you need to read the standard (here RFC 3315).